# Create a function with multiple conditionals to assign values to a column in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, function, conditional-statements

I have a Dataframe that looks like this in R:

**df**

| date | location | daytype | season | shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-9-1 | NT | Thur | spring | morning |
| 2022-9-2 | NT | Fri | summer | morning |
| 2022-9-3 | AP | Sat | summer | afternoon |
| 2022-9-4 | AP | Sun | fall | morning |
| 2022-9-5 | NT | Mon | winter | afternoon |

I want to create a new column for an end time for the shift depending on the shift and season in the dataframe.

Currently my code is this:

```
endtime = function(x){
  if(x %in% "Spring" & shift %in% "morning") return("01:00 PM")
  if(x %in% "Summer" & shift %in% "morning") return("01:30 PM")
  if(x %in% "Fall" & shift %in% "morning") return("01:00 PM")
  if(x %in% "Winter" & shift %in% "morning") return("12:30 PM")
  if(x %in% "Spring" & shift %in% "afternoon") return("06:00 PM")
  if(x %in% "Summer" & shift %in% "afternoon") return("07:00 AM")
  if(x %in% "Fall" & shift %in% "afternoon") return("06:00 PM")
  if(x %in% "Winter" & shift %in% "afternoon") return("05:00 PM")
}

df$endtime = sapply(calendar$Season, endtime)
```

But you cannot have more than two conditions with an if function. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if/else is not vectorized.  We may either use `ifelse` or `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(endtime = case_when(
      Season %in% "Spring" & shift %in% "morning" ~ "01:00 PM",
      Season %in% "Summer" & shift %in% "morning"~ "01:30 PM",
      ...
       
     ))
```

---

Or another option is to create a key/val dataset and do a join

```
keyval <- tibble(Season = c("Spring", "Summer"), 
  shift = c("morning", "morning"), endtime = c("01:00 PM", "01:30 PM"))
left_join(df, keyval)
```